# Map multiple subdomains on a single cloudfront instance to multiple s3 buckets

Tags: amazon-s3, dns, amazon-cloudfront

I am trying to map multiple subdomains on a single cloudfront instance to multiple s3 buckets. For example I have two subdomains www.foo.com and www.bar.com which have cname entries in the dns zone files  pointing to the cloudfront instance (xyz.cloudfront.net). In cloudfront I have added both www.foo.com and www.bar.com in the alternatives cnames. I have also created two s3 buckets which are added as origins to the cloudfront instance example s3.foo-amazon.com and s3.bar-amazon.com. Now how do I make sure that for www.bar.com content from s3.bar-amazon.com is requested and for www.foo.com contents for s3.foo-amazon.com is requested?

Answer (score 1):

I think you should create separate CloudFront distributions. Each will have a one CNAME and one origin pointing to the correct S3 bucket.